# Admin LTE data table jquery not working

Tags: angular

First of all I am sorry for my bad english.
I'm using Admin LTE 2 template for my project ,it works almost fine .But I have a problem . There is jquery of searching and ordering , `lengthChange` is not work  as template 
here is my

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { error } from 'util';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Shop } from '../../../entities/shop.entity';
import { ShopService } from '../../../services/shop.service';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../../../entities/user.entity';
import { THIS_EXPR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { ListShop } from '../../../entities/listshop.entity';

declare const $;
window['$'] = window['jQuery'] = $;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listshop',
  templateUrl: './listshop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listshop.component.css']
})
export class ListshopComponent implements OnInit {
  listshops:ListShop[];
  shops:Shop[];
  constructor(
    private shopservice :ShopService,
    private userservice :UserService

  ) { 
    $(function () {
      $('#example1').DataTable()
      $('#example2').DataTable({
        'paging'      : true,
        'lengthChange': true,
        'searching'   : true,
        'ordering'    : true,
        'info'        : true,
        'autoWidth'   : true
      })
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
```

## example2 and #example1 are  id of tag table contain datatable  in html file

am i missing  some thing ?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having (i.e. error message)? Are `#example1` and `#example2` DOM nodes in your component template?

Comment: i did't get any error message . #example1 and #example2  are id of
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

in file component.html

Comment: Your template code isn't in the DOM when your constructor runs. Did you try to move that jQuery code to your `ngAfterViewInit` method. At that point in the Angular lifecycle, your template will be rendered in the browser.